# Block request according to it's ISP?

Tags: http, nginx, server, ip

I am wondering if it is possible to block requests according to the ISPs? If yes, then how can I achieve that? I know I can block the requests if I know the range of IP addresses the ISP is assigned to. Is there any way to know those IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

You can achive that using the built in geoip module.

```
nginx -V
```

Look for `--with-http_geoip_module`

Then you will get a database and extract it to `/etc/nginx`:

```
wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz
gunzip GeoIP.dat.gz
```

Now add the following to your `nginx.conf`:

```
geoip_country /etc/nginx/GeoIP.dat;
map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country {
default yes;
CN no;
}
```

This example will allow anyone but not china. Now to activate it in appropriate location:

```
 if ($allowed_country = no) {
     return 443;
 }
```

Now this applies to isp too, You just need to get appropriate database.